# Как разобраться со всем разнообразием библиотек, framework'ов и т.д. для C++ на Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, .net, qt, c++

Есть знания C++. Допустим, надо написать программу. Можно ее написать разными способами. Можно с помощью Qt, можно через Win32, можно через MFC и т.д. Зависит от того, что будет делать программа. Но для этого надо знать какие есть способы и что они могут.

1. Какие есть самые популярные способы? Я в этом всем запутался.
2. .NET для C++. Как конкретно этот способ называется? C++/CLI?
3. Эти способы обычно совмещаются? Допустим есть библиотека, которая решают что-то одно, например, графические библиотеки GTK/FLTK/wxWidgets. А если этого не достаточно, то чем то дополняют или используют тот способ, в котором есть все что нужно?
4. Можете описать задачи, которые выполняют эти способы(хотя бы сказать про самые популярные типа Qt, Win32)? В описании этих способов все как-то расплывчато написано. Для меня пока это не очень понятно.
5. Framework отличается от библиотеки тем, что он имеет более широкую функциональность?
6. Мне Qt нравится тем, что там много чего есть, хотя я им не разу пользовался. Но я не знаю востребован ли Qt на рынке труда. Не могу пока определиться, что лучше учить. Qt, Win32 или еще что-то.

Comment: Qt - учить. Однозначно.

Comment: wxWidgets значитеьно больше, чем графическая библиотека

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Что подразумевается под способами? Вы уже выбрали язык. Можете разве что выбрать ту среду, в которой будете работать, и компилятор, которым собирать, а еще библиотеки, с помощью которых уменьшите объем работы.
2. Да, C++/CLI.
3. Еще раз. Это не способы. Вы назвали библиотеки. Действительно, можно писать на голом С++, но это очень трудоемко. И программы будут консольные. Сейчас это уже для большинства задач неприменимо. Получается, что придется все равно использовать какие-то вызовы для конкретных платформ - Windows, Linux. Уже получается какая-то привязка к определенной ОСи и ее интерфейсам. Вот смотрите. В Windows существует минимум три интерфейса, с помощью которых можно что-либо сделать:

   - Native API — самые низкоуровневые вызовы. Идут через библиотеку NTDLL.DLL в само ядро.
   - Win32 API — обертка вокруг Native API для обеспечения работоспособности классических Windows-программ. Обеспечивает работу граф. интерфейса, сеть и пр. Работа Win32API обеспечивается подключением кучи библиотек, но основные — это KERNEL32.DLL, USER32DLL и GDI32.DLL
   - MFC — библиотека, разработанная M$ для облегчения участи программистов, т.к. писать на голом WinAPI весьма грустно. Очень много вызовов, Win32 API не объектноориентирован в категориях С++ и пр.
4. Читайте описание. Задачи разные. Native API разрабатывался для обеспечения работы самой операционной системы. Поэтому с его помощью можно творить такие вещи, которые с помощью других интерфейсов нереально сделать. Правда приходится расплачиваться двумя моментами: недокументированностью и сложностью использования. Никто не гарантирует, что в следующей версии ОС этот интерфейс кардинально не изменят. WinAPI — это сложившийся интерфейс для написания графических приложений под среду Windows. Qt и MFC — это еще более высокоуровневые библиотеки, в которых есть множество модулей, начиная от работы с графическим интерфейсом (причем это проще, чем работать напрямую через WinAPI), кончая работой с конкретными типами файлов (аудио-видео) и сетью.
5. Понятно, что MFC под линукс нет. И если вы хотите кроссплатформенное приложение, то нужно использовать библиотеки, которые более широко распространены. Тот же Qt. Задача какая? Просто писать программу, не отвлекаясь на специфику каждой из платформ. Да и Qt сам по себе более мощен, чем MFC, но это на мой взгляд. Никто не мешает взять, да и самому произвести сравнительный анализ.
6. Framework по отношению к .net подразумевает, что это не просто библиотека, а среда. Среда выполнения программ. И, в принципе, существуют совместимые с .net среды, вроде проекта mono. А библиотека - ну, она одна. Или их несколько. Они реализуют какой-то функционал. Но он не такой всеобъемлющий как в framework'е, который предоставляет функции практически на все случаи жизни. И есть более мелкие отличия — как-то, что фреймворк имеет свой формат исполняемых файлов, свой загрузчик таких файлов и пр.

Хорошая блок-схема, разъясняющая взаимоотношения между разными интерфейсами:

[image: block]

Comment: Даже не знаю, что ответить. Знаний нет. Ну вот возьмем такой пример. Человек учит С++ сперва в консоли. Потом он захочет не много графики, GUI, работа с БД, сеть, многопоточность и т.д. Что в этом случае можно использовать? Какую библиотеку или framework? У меня пока есть только один вариант - Qt. WinAPI не объектно-ориентирован и не прост. C++/CLI еще можно. Там тоже много чего удобного и готового есть как в C#.

Comment: У Qt есть недостатки. Например, недостаток в том, что эта библиотека очень "тяжелая". Также проблема, что если Вы будете распространять свою программу (по крайней мере под Win), то придется Qt включать в дистрибутив. А при использовании Win32API все библиотеки уже есть в составе Microsoft Windows. Таким образом мы приходим к выводу, что нужно иметь представление о всех возможных средствах. А далее просто выбирать по конкретному применению. Но до Qt я бы обязательно обратил внимание на STL и boost.

Comment: А до этого я бы разобрался в чем различия между MSVC++ разных версий, gcc, g++, watcom c и пр. компиляторами.